# New member registrations with large file uploads

Tags: members, solspace

I am using the Solspace User for new registrations and want to allow new registrations the ability to upload large files in the user registration form.  I need to allow up to 6 large files, ie: 6 files up to 10mb each.

I thought about DevDemon's channel files as it allows for large uploads, but don't think it works with user registration forms.

Is there any other ideas to allow large file uploads in a User member registration form?

Maybe the only other option is to create a second SAEF using Channel files and get a member to be fill out the second form after their registration. (not ideal for me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right after registration, you can send your users to a SafeCracker form. The form could be on the same page as the registation form, with a segment to tell the template to display the SafeCracker form instead of the registration form.

Users can then upload their file through the SafeCracker form, and the author of the entry would be the logged in user.

As for the file size, make sure your upload_max_filesize setting in PHP is high enough to accept a 10 Mb file (this can typically be modified by editing php.ini), and that your EE upload directory also allows large file uploads. You can modify the file size limit in EE's File Manager in the Control Panel.

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I figured would be the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

What about using one of the Channel/Member linking add-ons, such as [Zoo Visitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor) or [Profile:Edit](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit)? That way you combine member registration and creation of a linked channel entry (and hence the ability to have custom upload fields for each member).